# Can we fix the size of Dropbox?

Tags: c#, html, css

On one of the web page in my application. I noticed that size of dropbox changes when I moved from 17" screen to 15". My question is Can we fix the size of dropbox so that when I moved from 17" screen to 15" it should not change?

17" Screen

[image]

15 "Screen

[image]

I am only worried about the size of dropbox. Please help here.

Below is my div from code:

```
<div class="col-md-3 hidebtnmobile">
     <div class="col-md-7" style="width: 46%">
         @Html.DropDownList("ChangeStatus", Model.GetAllStatus().OrderBy(l => l.Text), "-- Multi Status Change --")
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-5" style="padding-left: 0;">
        <button class="btn large primary-bg " style="margin-right: 5px; font-size: 12px;" title="Status Change" onclick=" ChangeMultiStatus(); return false;">Multi-Status</button>
     </div>
</div
```

>

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the column size changing when the resolution of the display changes.  You can give your dropdown list a class and then apply a minimum width to the dropdown list.

view:

```
@Html.DropdownList("ChangeStatus", Model.GetAllStatus().OrderBy(l => l.Text), "-- Multi Status Change --", new { @class = "ddl-fixed" })
```

css:

```
.ddl-fixed {
    min-width: ##px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the style property of the DropDownList to be a percentage.

```
<div class="col-md-7" style="width: 46%">
     @Html.DropDownList("ChangeStatus", Model.GetAllStatus().OrderBy(l => l.Text), "-- Multi Status Change --")
 </div>
```

Percentage widths often result in the DropDownList changing with screen size.  Changing the DropDownList styling to a constant width measurement, such as pixels (px), should prevent the "Dropbox" from changing sizes on different screens.  See the code below for the change.  "50" can be whatever number you like.

```
<div class="col-md-7" style="width: 50px">
     @Html.DropDownList("ChangeStatus", Model.GetAllStatus().OrderBy(l => l.Text), "-- Multi Status Change --")
 </div>
```

Comment: changing width to px works for me but now th eproblem is on 15" screen button besides the dropbox does down

Comment: I think that's because the Dropbox's width is too big a number.  Try making the pixel width a lot smaller until it hides some of the Dropbox.  Then increase the Dropbox's pixel-width a few pixels at a time until you can see the whole Dropbox.  There should be a pixel-width where you can see the whole Dropbox, but it does not push the button next to it down.  You can also try adding a "left-margin: #px" style property to the button.

Answer (score 0):

yes by this way you can fix the size:

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="width: 180px;">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ChangeStatus", Model.GetAllStatus().OrderBy(l => l.Text), "-- Multi Status Change --")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left: 0;">
                    <button class="btn large primary-bg " style="margin-right: 5px; font-size: 12px;" title="Status Change" onclick=" ChangeMultiStatus(); return false;">Multi-Status</button>
                </div>
```